# IIS 10 custom .NET authentication for FTP site

Tags: c#, ftp, gac, iis-10

I've set up an IIS FTP site on Windows 10, and disabled Basic and Anonymous authentication. I've also made a .NET authentication provider implementing

```
BaseProvider, IFtpAuthenticationProvider
```

The overridden method returns true in all cases, so I would expect any user/password combination to be accepted, alas, none I have thought to try are... Here is the class in all its glory:

```
    public class PartnerFtpAuth : BaseProvider, IFtpAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public bool AuthenticateUser(string sessionId, string siteName, string userName, string userPassword,
        out string canonicalUserName)
        {
            canonicalUserName = userName;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I've got the provider registered and enabled fine, it sits in the GAC, and the IIS settings look like the below:

[image: IIS Config]

When I try to authenticate with FileZilla I get the below:

```
Response:   530-User cannot log in.
Response:    Win32 error:   
Response:    Error details: An error occurred during the authentication process.
Response:   530 End
```

I'm slightly lost, anybody have any guidance?

Comment: Attach a debugger and debug.

Comment: Yeah... attaching a debugger isn't working - find the process ID from task manager, attach to that process in VS, it won't load symbols therefore won't hit a breakpoint. Would be nice if I just hadn't thought of debugging though.